# JavaFX css themes

Tags: css, user-interface, javafx, themes

Are there any free, ready-to-use css themes to customize the overall look & feel of a JavaFX application, like the default modena.css?

It would be nice to gather here a list of available stylesheets.

Comment: [AquaFX](http://aquafx-project.com/project.html) gives you ready to use Mac OS look and feel. You can go through the [JFXtras](http://www.guigarage.com/2013/01/this-is-for-the-native-ones/) project as well.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Guigarage](http://www.guigarage.com/) provides 3 out-of-the-box styles.

- AquaFX, a native look & feel for Mac OSX
- [AeroFX](https://github.com/guigarage/aerofx), that gives you the look of a Windows Forms app for Windows 7
- [Flatter](http://www.guigarage.com/2013/09/flatter/), a flat-design gui theme

Feel free to complete this list by answering the question.

Comment: links are outdated

Answer (score 21):

JavaFX Themes/ Look and feels:

- JMetro: "...a Java, JavaFX theme influenced by Microsoft's Fluent Design System (previously named Metro)" - [Java, JavaFX theme JMetro page](https://pixelduke.com/java-javafx-theme-jmetro)
- jbootfx: "A Javafx bootstrap theme.." - https://github.com/dicolar/jbootx
- MaterialFX: Google Material Design appearance in JavaFX - http://www.agix.pt/single-post/2015/09/02/MaterialFX-Material-Design-CSS-for-JavaFX
- AquaFX: "Aqua is a JavaFX theme that imitates the Look of Mac OS applications" - http://www.guigarage.com/aquafx/ - Their license says you can only use AquaFX on Apple hardware running Apple OS
- AeroFX: "AeroFX is a JavaFX theme that imitates the Look of Window 7 applications" - http://www.guigarage.com/aerofx/

Other themes with less polish:

- Flat Red: A red and flat (as the name implies) theme - https://github.com/carldea/jfx9be/tree/master/chap15/LookNFeelChooser/src/jfx9be
- Flatter: "Flatter is made for touch and embedded devices", like the name suggests it has a flat design - http://www.guigarage.com/2013/09/flatter/
- Sky: Theme based on blue color (hence the name "Sky") - https://github.com/carldea/jfx9be/tree/master/chap15/LookNFeelChooser/src/jfx9be

Comment: Tested JMetro with Java17 and JFX 17, not working.

There is a workaround explained in this link: https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras-styles/issues/214

Answer (score 10):

Here is another theme:

- [JavaFX bootstrap](https://github.com/dicolar/jbootx), JavaFX versions of the bootstrap themes of version 2 and 3

Answer (score 3):

`MistSilver Skin` best theam looks like matle. https://github.com/farrukh-obaid/javafx-skins/tree/master/src/MistSilver

**Edit**

`Previous link` is **not working** now, you can find this one working https://github.com/tianyow/javafx-skins

Comment: Link not working `404 Not Found`

Comment: @PranjalCholadhara Yeah right! That's link is now broken, This link can now be used https://github.com/tianyow/javafx-skins